# How Can decode sha1 code?

Tags: javascript, sha1

**I have a code but i can't decode it so i need help for you. Please help me.
Firstly I don't know it type. What is it ? sha1 ? md5 ? hash ? i know just this code have 40 character.**

How can decode this security code ? it's have game score so i need decode it but i can't decode it.

This code:  "security":"**c6aefe7f8c9fd439f59635efc82fcbd4f6cd4b9c**"

it's protect game inform. When I changed anything, it's not confirm security code.

Full Code:   `{"security":"c6aefe7f8c9fd439f59635efc82fcbd4f6cd4b9c","time":40844,"numberOfBirdsShot":2,"type":"LevelComplete","blocks":"800,100,130,130,130,130,310,110,300,300,110,10,150,70,120,60,40,60,60,110,130,80,70,140,180,20,190,20,40,40,90,70,10,10,40,10,40,190,190,40,40,50,20,130,20,140,10,60,90,120,120,10,10,80,100,120,30,90,90,290,100,80,120,70,70,370,150,50,50,160,160,10,30,250,160,180,180,130,70,70,130,60,30,30,130,320,70,70,170,70,150,40,40,90,30,110,120,270,60,40,180,140,220,30,20,160,460,10,30,70,110,350,290,700,550,90,100,90,10,100,40,40,80,40,40,170,80,80,70,70,70,120,170,10,20,50,10,10,40,70,70,50,20,80,80,20,20,90,220,220,230,50,20,20,80,60,30,30,280,90,50,260,80,120,80,80,50,110,90,20,20,30,30,60,70,40,40,10,30,110,100,50,40,50,100,90,20,20,30,160,10,10,20,10,10,90,70,30,210,180,90,80,80,40,160,60,30,80,80,80,0,500,5000,500,500,500,500,5000,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,5000,500,500,5000,500,500,500,500,500,500,0,10000,10000","sessionID":"2DAB169CF4F766CC69CA2C5A02339CB7.f119dcaaa5c087f52aa2ad687312f9f46d402972","levelID":"1-1","score":73150,"gameplay":"WIN1-1@@2@321:16.489984194253722:-25.291503791549072:1:-161.45947702629903@505:16.306849998012037:-27.166930977940375:1:172.61390103177405@@2@333@517@@0","userLevelID":"0c4679cd-5fb0-441e-a257-a060010bdb3d","userID":"1a7c1755-a7e7-48a0-9e7d-a04a0142a595"}`

Comment: Um... good. Voting to close as no-one's ever going to find your hash useful in the future.

Comment: You need to learn what _hashing_ means.

Comment: @SLaks this subject about if i send you video your mail , can you look it ?

Answer (score 6):

You  can't decode a `sha1` hash.

> A cryptographically strong hash function exhibits two features: **it is irreversible** and it minimizes collisions. Irreversibility means that the original data cannot be reconstructed from its hash. Cf. encryption, which must be reversible (see write-only memory.) A collision occurs when two different sets of data generate the same hash.

Comment: +1, And although irreversible you can use a [lookup table](http://www.sha1-lookup.com/)

Comment: OP won't get it. I confirmed it's not in any tables I've found before posting the link. ;-) But also stresses that if a look-up table is necessary, it's a tough nut to crack. ;-) (Although I've read that for a few dollars you can take advantage of AWS' computing power and break it in a couple days or so. ;p)

Comment: @BradChristie even if you found some string that hashed to this `sha1`, it wouldn't be the same as the original string used to create this hash.

Comment: hmm thanks for inform . if you have time ,i can show it on teamviewer or video.

Comment: Please give me your mail adress , i will send video.

Answer (score 1):

If it has 40 characters of hex, then that's 20 bytes or 160 bits which would suggest it's SHA-1.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible (in a reasonable amount of time). What you can do is check rainbowtables or try to find hash collisions.

Comment: Hmm I understand, thanks .if you have time ,i can show it on teamviewer or video

Comment: Please give me your mail adress , i will send video.